# How to properly install c++ libraries when using mingw?

Tags: c++, mingw

I am having trouble installing a c++ audio library called BASS(https://www.un4seen.com/). I have dumped the **bass.h** file into the mingw32 include directory. I have also put the **bass.dll** file in the lib section of the compiler. Whenever I try to use the any of the functions or methods that are included in the bass.h file I get an ERROR, telling me there was no reference to the function at all. Interestingly, my IDE visual studio code recognizes the bass.h file with all the methods and functions. Which leaves to think, what have done wrong?

I have some suspicion that I put in the wrong bass.dll because the file includes 10 different .dll files that differentiate between the 32 bit and 64 bit.

Comment: Is the error a compilation error or a linker error?  If it's a linker error you probably need to link against the library's .lib or .a files.

Comment: It was a linker error because the compiler didn't know where the .dll file was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's telling you there's no reference to that function, then you're probably not linking the library properly. You have to use the `-l` flag to link the DLL to you project. If there are more DLLs, as you think there are, you can still use this flag to link them. If you need to include a directory of libraries, use `-L`.
Check this link (MinGW's website) for more info: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use

Comment: It worked but it gave me this warning: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: resolving _BASS_Init@20 by linking to _BASS_Init
Use --enable-stdcall-fixup to disable these warnings
Use --disable-stdcall-fixup to disable these fixups